# How does Doctrine set private IDs

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In PHP, I can create a model with a private/protected `$id` variable and no setter.

Doctrine ORM is able to set that property when the object is saved/loaded.

How does this work internally? I assume this is handled by serialization, but I haven't been able to find the code responsible of this behavior.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first time doctrine instantiates an entity (such as a `User`), it does this:

```
$this->prototype = unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen($this->name), $this->name));
```

Which creates an object of that type without calling its constructor (deserialization avoids a call to `__construct`, and they do this intentionally so they don't have to worry about what your constructor looks like or does).

After the first object has been initialized, Doctrine uses `clone` to make new instances of the same object type.

```
$entity = clone $this->prototype;
```

From the cloned objects, it will:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionObject($entity);
$property = $reflection->getProperty('idField');
$property->setAccessible(true);
$property->setValue($entity, 123);
```

The actual code to do this is more complex due to Doctrine's support from compound primary keys, but this should hopefully guide you the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

Doctrine ORM uses [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to [assign identifiers](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L819). This is done in the [class metadata](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L679-L691) of your entity.

Un-serialization [is only used to create new instances](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L829-L831) (blueprints) of your entities when the ORM has to instantiate them internally without using constructor params. Once a blueprint is available, it is cloned for each new requested instance.

There's a blogpost on the official website [explaining how Doctrine creates new instances](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/21/doctrine-2-give-me-my-constructor-back.html) of your entities.